# Warning if Framework is not linked to project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm creating a static library to be use with several project and wonder if there is anyway to show warning if the project that import my static library is not yet link to all depending framework.

Says, if this static library depending on MapKit.framework and CoreLocation.framework, I want to show warning that some frameworks are missing.

(I know that when at build time, XCode will throw symbol not found if the depending framework is not linked properly, but still, wanna show friendly message instead.)

Comment: where do you want to show that message as build can not be compile?

Comment: Don't worry the linker will give plenty of messages if a framework is missing.  You just need to document what the error messages mean and how to solve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use language extension to check the presence of a header file using the __has_include .

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#include-file-checking-macros

Answer (score 1):

You can not show a message since app would not compile if a dependency is missing hence you code will never run till user adds the required frameworks.

The best way to deal with that is, first of all properly document the dependencies and then add a troubleshooting section somewhere in the documentation listing all possible errors caused by missing frameworks with instructions to resolve them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, still, I hope there will be a way to do this. I see in some AFNetworking that when you build, it will show a warning  if you not link SystemConfiguration.framework and MobileCoreService.framework ... I'm just wondering how Matt did that and think it would be great to add to the lib I'm working on

Comment: Well that is Xcode throwing up warnings not AFNetworking code, which is open source, you should be able to take a look at it if you like.